# IIS7 301 URL rewrite gives 200 status rather than 301 status

Tags: redirect, iis-7, http-status-code-301

I'm testing some URL redirects for a new client site.  The old site was a static HTML site, the new site is an ASP.NET site.  I need to redirect some old '.htm' URLs which will no longer exist on the new site to the equivalent new .aspx pages.

I've added some rules in the web.config file like this:

```
  <rewrite>
      <rules>
          <rule name="Rule 1">
              <match url="index.htm" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="/" redirectType="Permanent" />
          </rule>
          <rule name="Rule 2">
              <match url="whatwedo.htm" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="/about-us.aspx" redirectType="Permanent" />
          </rule>
      </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

This seems to work, in that when I load the URL in the browser: http://www.myclientsite.com/whatwedo.htm it does actually display the /about-us.aspx page.  However, the address stays the same in the address bar (http://www.myclientsite.com/whatwedo.htm) which I didn't really expect.  This made me curious, so I've used a bunch of online '301 redirect checker' services and also Firebug and Chrome dev tools to check what's going on, and they all seem to just say there's no redirect happening - they just give 200 status messages on the .htm page.

I'm keen to get this right as there are some important SEO implications if this goes wrong, so I wondered if anyone could confirm that this is correct behaviour or whether it is wrong somehow and not doing a proper 301 redirect?  If it's wrong, how can I correct it to perform a true 301 redirect?

Thanks for any pointers folks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `<action type="Redirect" url="..." redirectType="Permanent" />` to redirect the request rather than rewrite.

Comment: Absolutely spot on! Thanks Craig - I didn't realise there were two different options there (redirect or rewrite) but it makes a lot of sense now.  Thank you!!